# Order statistics CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

I am just learning about order statistics and limiting distributions. I was looking through the many examples in my book covering this subject and there is one small detail I can't figure out.

Some context: suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample from a Pareto distribution, $X_{i} \sim PAR(1,1)$, and let $Y_{n} = nX_{1:n}$. The CDF of $X_{i}$ is $F(x)=1-(1+x)^{-1};x>0$.
Then the book gives the CDF of $Y_{n}$, denoted by $G_{n}(y)$:

$$G_{n}(y) = 1 - \left(1 + \frac{y}{n}\right)^{-n}, \quad y>0.$$

I understand how the CDF of the smallest order statistics is derived. It is given as $G_{1}(y_{1}) = 1 - [1-F(y_{1})]^{n}$. This, I can derive without any problems, however I don't understand how the times $n$ in front of $X_{1:n}$ is used in determining $G_{n}(y)$. Sometimes the smallest or the biggest order statistics is multiplied by $n$ or $1/n$ and in both cases I can't do the necessary calculations. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I can give more examples if needed.

Comment: You mention order statistics but where are they in your problem?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor correct me if I am wrong, but $X_{1:n}$ denotes the smallest order statistics right? So, I do have them mentioned in my question.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that notation.  If $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are a set of random variables, $X_{(1)}$ represents the first (lowest) value, $X_{(2)}$ represents the second lowest, and so on, with $X_{(n)}$ representing the largest value.  That $X_{1:n}$ notation is totally unclear whether you mean the first, the last, the whole set, or what, as well as how you would refer to a particular order statistic.  Where did you see that notation?

Comment: My apologies, in your case I am looking for $nX_{(1)}$ then.

Comment: It's written this way in the book we use for statistics.

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: Introduction to probability and mathematical statistics by Bain and Engelhardt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124182/discussion-between-murat-and-robertthetutor).

Comment: $G_n(y)=P(X_{1:n}\le y/n)=G_1(y/n)=\cdots$